# SQL Server Developer Edition versus SQL Server Standard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, database, development

not sure I understand this but I am going to throw my assumption out there:

SQL Server 2008 Standard & Enterprises editions are for running full database services on server (not just but for comparative sake),

and SQL Server Developer Edition is what, an IDE for developing programs around SQL Server???

not sure I understand?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Developer Edition is just Enterprise Edition without the license to be used in a Production environment. Also, it doesn't need to be installed on a Server OS (ie, you can put it on Win7, Vista, XP).

Comment: I believe that it is also limited to just a few connections vs. Enterprise Edition.

Comment: @Joe Internet: Where have you seen this? I've never seen any such connection limit documented? Everything I've seen just indicates the different licence and no installation limit to servers.

Comment: I don't think that's true, Joe. I've happily done stress testing using Developer Edition before.

Comment: @Richard, @Rob Farley - Yeah, I think you guys are right. I read it somewhere recently, and was a bit surprised, because I didn't think that was the case. I should have checked my facts when I read it.

Comment: Developer edition might have the 1 CPU limit on it.  Is that true?

Comment: No, not true. I've used it with multiple CPUs.

Comment: I think the limit actually comes from the operating system. You're not allowed more than ten (IIRC) connections to a service on a workstation OS. Thus, SQL Dev Edition on a workstation OS shouldn't have more than 10 inbound connections, otherwise you **may** be in violation of the license.